# How to log table information using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logging, timestamp

I have the following table (df):

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | finished | 1234 |
| A2 | ongoing | 1235 |
| A3 | NaN | 1236 |
| A4 | finished | 1237 |
| A5 | started | 1238 |
| A6 | finished | 1239 |

I would like to log the information from that table that is not finished as log.log file. How do I do that?

**Desired output:**

```
12/12/2010 11:46:36 AM A2 ongoing 1235
12/12/2010 11:46:36 AM A3 NaN 1236
12/12/2010 11:46:36 AM A5 started 1238
```

What I tried so far?

```
import pandas as pd
import logging

tab_not_finished = df[df['col2'] != 'finished']
logging.basicConfig(filename='log.log', encoding='utf-8', format = '%(asctime)s %(message)s',  level=logging.WARNING)
logging.warning(tab_not_finished)
```

The above script does not save as log file with timestamp. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your table to string with `to_string`:

```
logging.warning(tab_not_finished.to_string())
```

eventually prepend a newline, or the header will be on the timestamps' line:

```
logging.warning('\n'+tab_not_finished.to_string())
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! But I am unable to extract the NaN rows and does not have timestamp. How do I do that?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to remove the NaNs? `tab_not_finished.dropna()`

Comment: No, I want to include the NaNs.

Comment: The NaNs should be included, works for me… which pandas version do you have?

Comment: Pandas version 1.1.2

Comment: I don't know what to say, check all intermediates `tab_not_finished`, `tab_not_finished.to_string()`, etc.